# Spring MVC template engin vs plane html

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm a little confused about template engines like thymeleaf or velocity.

My question is are there any profits from using template engine instead plain html + angular?

I'm asking because I'm developing application using

```
Spring boot 1.3.2
Angular 1.4.8
Thymeleaf
```

and I'm wondering if is a chance in Spring MVC application that I'll nead template engine instead make it all in plain hmtl + angular?

Comment: AngularJS is a client-side technology and Thymeleaf is server-side-oriented so they're completely unrelated. Also, Thymeleaf's end product is "plain HTML".

Answer (score 0):

- AngularJS is as client-side Javascript framework.
- Thymeleaf is a server-side template engine capable of create HTML, CSS, Javascript and text.

You can use both to create your web app.

For instance you can send to your customers already processed pages by Thymeleaf with the client specific data. As the customer interacts with your page you can use AngularJS to bring data from your server via Ajax or to process his requests locally, so your server will not need to send the entire page to your customer as he interacts with your page, this will make your page faster.

Comment: My question was, is Thymeleaf give me any benefit versus Angular, to be considered as template engine worth of use.

Comment: If you will construct your page without real-time interactions of your user is worthier to use Thymeleaf.
If your responses need to be sent to your user according with his interaction Angular is better.

To build the heavy information(first load) with Thymeleaf and to send specific small changes with Angular is the best flow.